# New column depending on conditions sql

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

Let's say that I have a table with 2 columns, like this:

[image: table]

And I want to add another column if the ID has the type `credit card`. How to do that?

Comment: All rows of a table have the same number of columns. What are you trying to do? Please show us the result that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly then you can use `case` expressions to add another column as following

```
select
  ID,
  Type,
  case 
    when Type = 'Credit Card' then yourValue
  end as yourColumnName
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when type = 'Credit Card' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as has_credit_card
from t;
```